# Why won't my post request work on the browser but works in Postman?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

My React.js project and Laravel project are separated.

1. I login as an authenticated user in Postman using this endpoint (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login`)
2. I then upload a file using this (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/wall-of-fame`)

All works fine - user's logged in and that logged in user can successfully upload a file to the db along with their `user_id`, `email`, and `file_path`.  I get `inserted successfully` in Postman in the response body.

The only thing that's very very weird about this working's that I'm not using an access token to successfully upload the aforementioned data to the db in Postman.

However, when I try the above 2 steps on the browser - I get a `200` when checking the Network tab but nothing's being stored in the db.  I'm using an access token because how else can I recognize an authenticated user on the client side?  I get `failed` in the response body on the browser.

Since this process works in Postman, my inclination's that something's off with the frontend and my possibly my Axios call.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here's `Upload.js` code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null,
            id: null,
            email: ''
        };
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Inside componentDidMount()");
        let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
        let email = localStorage.getItem("email");
        this.setState({
            id: id,
            email: email
        })
        console.log(id);
        console.log(email);
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fileUpload(this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.files }, () => this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    fileUpload(file) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token").slice(13,-8);

        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(this.state.id);
        console.log(this.state.email);
        console.log(file.name);
        formData.append('file',file);

        const headers = {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/wall-of-fame', formData, {headers})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form encType='multipart/form-data' id="login-form" className="form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        );
    }

}

export default Upload;
```

Here's `FileUploadController.php` code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Photo;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FileUploadController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $user = Auth::user();

//        dd($user);

        if($user) {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $email = Auth::user()->email;
            $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
            $data = [
                'file_path' => $filePath,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'email' => $email
            ];
            DB::table('db.photos')->insert($data);
            return "inserted successfully";
        }

    return "failed";

    }
}
```

Here's `Auth.php` login method:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);

    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);

    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;

    if ($request->remember_me) {
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    }

    $token->save();

    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString(),
        $user
    ]);
}
```

Here's my `User.php` file (model):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'user_id', 'file_path'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function photos() {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
    }
}
```

Here's my `Photo.php` file (model):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Here's `api.php` file:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
      return $request->user();
    });
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
    Route::post('wall-of-fame', 'FileUploadController@store');

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
        Route::get('wall-of-fame', 'FileUploadController@fileUpload');
    });
});
```

Comment: Look into your FileUploadController. When it Returns "failed" it must be the case that `$user = Auth::user();` returns a non-true value.

Comment: @steven but the thing is that it doesn't return a non-true value.  When I call `dd($user);` it returns the correct information of the currently logged in user in Postman.

Comment: Yes, in postman. But obviously not when you call it from react. Please inspect this.

Comment: using passport? be sure you add the "fresh token"  to the web kernel https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],